# Creating a folium map with dataframe location data

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I am having a problem and would love help.

I have created a data frame in pandas that contains sets of latitude and longitude coordinates of businesses in a town.
I have loaded the folium library and created a map of the town. The problem is that I don't know how to import the data frame information to make markers on the map.

This is all done in a Jupiter notebook with python 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- K

Comment: please show us what you have tried already, so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a code in dataframe format for the list format in the official reference. Please refer to [this](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers) and [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/MarkerCluster.ipynb).

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

LA_location = pd.DataFrame({
    'Los Angeles':['Hollywood Sign','Griffith Observatory','Disneyland Park'],
    'latitude':[34.134082, 34.118333, 33.8046],
    'longtude':[-118.321635, -118.300333, -117.919],})

map = folium.Map(location=[34.11, -118.3], zoom_start=10)
for i, row in LA_location.iterrows():
    folium.Marker(location=[row['latitude'], row['longtude']], popup=row["Los Angeles"]).add_to(map)

map
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to map the information that I needed.